How do I remove space between the navigation bar and the view?
I am getting a lot of unnecessary space between the navigation bar and the beginning of the FormContent view. I tried putting top padding of the FormContent as 0, but it didn't work. How do I remove this whitespace?
NavigationStack {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                FormContent(formData: $formData, loadingState: $loadingState, focusedField: _focusedField, buttonAction: saveForm)
            }
            .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            
            if loadingState == .loading {
                LoadingView(text: "Saving...", fullScreen: false)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            focusedField = false
        }
        .overlay {
            if formData.showDatePicker {
                DatePickerSection(birthday: $formData.birthday, birthdayString: $formData.birthdayString, showDatePicker: $formData.showDatePicker, dateFormatter: vm.dateFormatter)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button {
                    focusedField = false
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("Add New Pet")
                    .poppinsBold(size: 16)
            }
        }
    }


If possible, can you update your sample code to not include any custom views?  Currently the code is not runnable by anyone else without those custom views. It's possible the issue lies in one of those views. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This space is reserved for the navigation title, but you are not showing one. So try applying .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) to the top-level ZStack:
ZStack {
    // ...
}
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) //  HERE

